# Book title in Revtex bibliography

Tags: bibtex, revtex

I'm writing an article using `revtex4-1` format, and in order to generate the bibliography I use the BibTeX style `apsrev4-1`.

The problem is that when I cite books, the book title does not break at the end of the column (nor the page in this case), as you might notice in the picture.

[image: Picture of bibliography]

What could I do to solve this behaviour? Thank you.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,aps,showpacs,showkeys,prd,superscriptaddress,byrevtex]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,latexsym,amssymb,amsfonts,epsfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ulem}
%\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[%
  colorlinks=true,
  urlcolor=blue,
  linkcolor=blue,
  citecolor=blue
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{breqn}

\makeatletter
\let\cat@comma@active\@empty
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{I'm here you're there}

\author{Oscar \surname{Castillo-Felisola}}

\section{\label{phenom}Phenomenological implications}

\cite{Cartan-Einstein,Cartan1922,*Cartan1923,*Cartan1924,*Cartan1925}

\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\bibliography{References.bib}
\end{document}
```

BibTeX entries

```
@Article{Cartan1922,
  author =   {Cartan, Elie},
  title =    {Sur une g\'en\'eralisation de la notion de courbure de Riemann et les espaces \`a torsion},
  journal =      {C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris},
  year =     {1922},
  volume =   {174},
  pages =    {593},
  url       =    {http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k3127j.image.langFR},
}

@article{Cartan1923,
  title={Sur les vari{\'e}t{\'e}s {\`a} connexion affine et la th{\'e}orie de la relativit{\'e} g{\'e}n{\'e}ralis{\'e}e (premi{\`e}re partie)},
  author={Cartan, Elie},
  journal={Ann. Ec. Norm. Super.},
  volume={40},
  pages={325},
  year={1923},
  organization={Soci{\'e}t{\'e} math{\'e}matique de France},
  url = "http://archive.numdam.org/article/ASENS_1923_3_40__325_0.pdf",
}

@article{Cartan1924,
  added-at = {2012-03-20T16:46:21.000+0100},
  author = {Cartan, Elie},
  biburl = {http://www.bibsonomy.org/bibtex/28d419192587558cbe5fb0ef3010fa947/marco.giovanell},
  interhash = {44a9d347ae2ea364f07c0e4e9cdcbfab},
  intrahash = {8d419192587558cbe5fb0ef3010fa947},
  journal = {Ann. Ec. Norm. Super.},
  keywords = {jabref:noKeywordAssigned},
  owner = {marco},
  pages = {1},
  timestamp = {2012-03-20T16:46:21.000+0100},
  title = {Sur les vari\'et\'es \`a connexion affine, et la th\'eorie de la relativit\'e
    g\'en\'eralis\'ee (premi\`ere partie) (Suite)},
  volume = {41},
  year = {1924},
  url = {http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/item?id=ASENS_1924_3_41__1_0},
}

@article{Cartan1925,
  added-at = {2012-03-20T16:46:21.000+0100},
  author = {Cartan, Elie},
  biburl = {http://www.bibsonomy.org/bibtex/2a42d27017aaeac461f63112c6604b814/marco.giovanell},
  interhash = {7b4e0980e917b55bf750d1c1fdee61c3},
  intrahash = {a42d27017aaeac461f63112c6604b814},
  journal = {Ann. Ec. Norm. Super.},
  keywords = {jabref:noKeywordAssigned},
  owner = {Marco},
  pages = {17},
  timestamp = {2012-03-20T16:46:21.000+0100},
  title = {Sur les vari\'et\'es \`a connexion affine et la th\'eorie de la relativit\'e
    g\'en\'eralis\'ee, Part II,},
  volume = {42},
  year = {1925},
  url = {http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/item?id=ASENS_1925_3_42__17_0},
}

@Book{Cartan-Einstein,
  editor =   {Debever, Robert},
  title =    {Elie Cartan - Albert Einstein Letters on Absolute Parallelism 1929-1932},
  publisher =    {Princeton University Press},
  year =     {1979},
}
```

Comment: can you post a bib file for those entries otherwise the example isn't really usable to test anything. Also don't load `epsfig` unless you absolutely need to emulate a document from 1986.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've added the BibTeX entries to the post, and thank you for the advise wrt `epsfig` package, I'll remove that from my source file!

Comment: The problem is `ulem` simplest is just not to use that, (the underline just looks ugly anyway even if it did linebreak)  or you could restore the original `\emph` before the bibliography, or do you really want `\emph` to be underline in the bibliography as well?

Comment: thank you @DavidCarlisle that was the problem if fact!I use the package `ulem` during the edition of the manuscript, but now I'll take it out for the final version. :-) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ulem` package is making an underline and preventing the title from being broken over a line in this context. Simply removing the package is simplest and then the title will be set in italics and break over a line with no issues.

Comment: Sounds like an incompatibility. Should revtex warn, if `ulem` was loaded?

Comment: @JonasStein I don't think so: underlining is so rare in published documents anyway, and any number of things could prevent line breaking. `\underline`, `\fbox` .... why single out ulem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes out from `ulem` as David Carlisle mentioned.
It was certainly explained in the [document](https://ctan.org/pkg/ulem).

> `ulem` normally replaces italics with underlining in text emphasized
> by `\emph`, and to some extent by `\em`. A declaration of `\normalem`
> or the `\usepackage` option `[normalem]` disables this feature.

I solved this problem by using

```
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
```

instead of

```
\usepackage{ulem}
```